# What is a קאפיזי"ש?

Tags: translation

I'm trying to understand the measurements quoted by the Abarbanel over here. https://mg.alhatorah.org/Full/Melakhim_I/5.2#e1n6

He says that: ונראה מזה שהיה מאכל שלמה בכל יום אלפים ושבע מאות פאניגא״ש לחם, שהם מאתים ועשרים וחמשה קאפיזי״ש ממדות קשטיליי״א, שהקאפי״ז כעין המויי״ו הנהוג במלכות פורטוגא״ל ארץ מולדתי,

What measurement is the פאניגא״ש? What about a קאפיזי״ש? And the last one here is a מויי"ו? He also mentions the טונבאלו״ש a little later, a measurement from Naples.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The first measurement listed there is a [Fanega](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fanega), and the Portuguese measurement is a [Moio](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moio_(unit)). I couldn't easily find the others, but hopefully this helps your understanding!

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Qafiz ?

Comment: @Kazibácsi I'm sure it is. Compare also קפיזא in Bavli Pesachim 48b

Comment: @JoelK I thought of posting the Talmiudic one, but I didn't know if the at secular equivalent was still in use in Spain 1000+ years later.

Comment: @Kazibácsi thanks!